# Nginx , save location path in url after redirect

Tags: nginx

I have the following configuration for nginx

```
 location /discord/ {
   rewrite ^/discord/(.*) /$1 break;
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8086/;
   proxy_pass_header Cookie;
   port_in_redirect off;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }

  location / {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8089/;
   proxy_pass_header Cookie;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
```

As you can see , I have two servers running on the same domain
The question is:

I have a link inside **http://127.0.0.1:8086/** . Let's say I want to visit default page , I open this link
**http://domain/discord** then I press the link in this page with path '/test' and I go to the following page  **http://domain/test** but I want to visit this page **http://domain/discord/test**

How can I configure Nginx to add **discord** prefix to urls inside  **http://127.0.0.1:8086/** page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try to do here, is trying to make the rewrite rules redirect visitors to different location based on the *previous path*

This will need the web server understand the [referer request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) which can only be implemented from application layer (eg. PHP) but not server configurations in my understanding

---

An approach is to use the *relative* path on the links, for example:

> Root document (rewritten by web server) under `http://domain/discord/`
>
> Absolute path: `href="/test"` => `http://domain/test`
>
> Relative path: `href="./test"` => `http://domain/discord/test`

You can change the location to rewrite in nginx in future and won't effect to relative paths

> Root document (rewritten by web server) under `http://domain/telegram/`
>
> Absolute path: `href="/test"` => `http://domain/test`
>
> Relative path: `href="./test"` => `http://domain/telegram/test`

Answer (score 0):

Add 'discord/test' as href to the link.

Comment: What if in future I want to change /discord to /telegram , then I will have to rewrite it in nginx config and in server routs . It should be done through nginx , not through my web server on port 8086